# Documentation for UI Testing in XCode 7

Tags: xcode, user-interface, ui-testing, xcode-ui-testing

I was wondering if there is any documentation for the new UI Testing in XCode 7 introduced at WWDC 2015. If there is no documentation, are there any user-produced versions that are worth looking at?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some of the useful links:

- [Apple developer videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=406)
- [Apple Developer Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/09-ui_testing.html)
- [mokacoding](http://www.mokacoding.com/blog/xcode-7-ui-testing/)

Comment: The Developer Doc will likely be added to once iOS 9 is public.

Answer (score 6):

I used [appledoc](https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc) to generate some unofficial headers of XCTest on iOS 9. This includes the new `XCU*` classes used in UI Testing.

- [Unofficial headers (viewable online)](http://masilotti.com/xctest-documentation/)
- [Downloadable docset (GitHub repo)](https://github.com/joemasilotti/XCTest-Documentation)

Comment: I just found your repo. You're awesome, man! Thanks!