# Xcode UI Test example

Tags: ios, xcode, ui-testing, xcode-ui-testing

I have just recently learned about [Unit Testing in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31570612/3681880). Now I am trying out Xcode 7 and I see there is a new group for UI Tests when I create a new project.

[image]

I watched the [WWDC 2015 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=406) and it was pretty good, but do you have a super simple example that I could go through myself? The video examples were a little too complex for me.

**Notes**

- The answer below is my attempt to figure this out, but I welcome any better answers.
- I have read these SO questions about UI Testing in Xcode but they are different: [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30882193/documentation-for-ui-testing-in-xcode-7), [reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521916/ios-ui-unit-testing-xcode7), [App vs UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521259/xcode-7-is-chasm-between-app-tests-and-ui-tests-unbridgeable), [ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31491713/how-to-test-launching-a-viewcontroller-xctest), [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397653/attempting-to-run-multiple-tests-using-xcodes-new-ui-testing-fails), [values and properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31250941/xcuielement-obtain-image-value), [pre XCode 7 projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886525/xcode-7-ui-test-cases-for-pre-xcode-7-projects).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use **Unit Tests** to test the validity of methods in your classes. You use them to test the code you have written. (See [my other example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31570612/3681880) for setting up a simple Unit Test in Xcode.)

Use **UI Tests** to check the validity of the User Interface. Think of it like having your own robot to go through and do all the normal interactions with your app that a normal user would. This saves you the time of doing it yourself.

At the time of this writing, it is difficult to access many of the properties of the UI components, but just having a test go through tapping them and swiping them confirms that they are there.

## Example

This is about the simplest setup and UI test that I could think of: a button that when pressed changes the text of a label.

## Set up

- Create a new project in Xcode 7+ for iOS 9.0+.
- Make sure that Include UI Tests is checked

[image]

- If you are adding UI tests to a project created before Xcode 7, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30923286/3681880). (File > New > Target > Test > Cocoa Touch UI Testing Bundle)
- Add a `UILabel` and a `UIButton` to the storyboard

[image]

- Create an @IBOutlet and @IBAction in the `ViewController` and make the `label` text change when the `button` is pressed.

  ```
  import UIKit
  class ViewController: UIViewController {
      @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
      @IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
          label.text = "Hello"
      }
  }
  ```

## Do the test

- Open the *YourProject*UITests file.

[image]

- Put your curser in the `testExample()` method. (You can delete the comments)

[image]

- Press the red Record button

[image]

- In the app, (1) tap the label, (2) tap the button, and then (3) tap the label again. (4) Press the Record button again to stop recording. The following code should have been automatically generated for you:

  ```
  func testExample() {

      let app = XCUIApplication()
      app.staticTexts["Label"].tap()
      app.buttons["Button"].tap()
      app.staticTexts["Hello"].tap()
  }
  ```
- Use the `staticText` lines as a starting point for making an `XCTAssert`. Now you should have:

  ```
  func testExample() {

      let app = XCUIApplication()
      XCTAssert(app.staticTexts["Label"].exists)
      app.buttons["Button"].tap()
      XCTAssert(app.staticTexts["Hello"].exists)
  }
  ```
- Press the diamond on the left to run the UI Test. It should turn green when it passes.

[image]

- That's it! This showed that the `UIButton` and `UILabel` exist and that the text of the label changed. If you want to see it fail (a good idea), you can change "Hello" to something else.

## Further study

- [UI Testing in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=406)
- [Exploring the New UI Testing Features of Xcode 7](http://www.danielhall.io/exploring-the-new-ui-testing-features-of-xcode-7)
- [Xcode 7 UI testing, a first look](http://www.mokacoding.com/blog/xcode-7-ui-testing/)
- [UI Testing in Xcode 7](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-xcode-7/)

Comment: How is it possible to make sure that it was the label that changed? If it is a button what is changed to "Hello" the test will also pass. One option would be to check that the label and button exists, but this is not generic. What if we want to change the label to empty string instead "Hello"? `app.staticTexts[""].exists` is almost always true.

Comment: Why can't we go for accessibilityIdentifer to identify elements instead of hardcoded text like "Hello". This always helps, even though the text is changed in future.

Comment: I'm sure that would probably be better. The above answer was something I made as I was trying to figure out UI Testing in the absence of any other simple examples. Feel free to add another answer to this question that improves on my answer.

Comment: Is there really no official documentation for how to write UI tests in iOS? I found this page https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/user_interface_tests but there's no examples and it's certainly not obvious that you would say something like XCTAssert(app.staticTexts["Label"].exists). Where's the official guide?

Answer (score 7):

[@Suragch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3681880/suragch) +1 for the answer. One thing I observed and want to share that every function inside the UI Test case must start with "test". You can append extra name after that. Only this way the button(for clicking to start the test) appears.

Comment: You can suggest for edit or comment. A separate answer does make sense.